# error 404 in user's my account magento

Tags: magento, module, account

I am creating a module for creating new tab in User's myaccount. I have successfully added a tab named "My Special Products".
Problem is that when i click on that tab it's redirect to 404 error page. I am not able to getting the problem.

My layout xml(customtabs.xml) code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<customer_account>
    <!-- Mage_Review -->
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" >
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer">
            <name>newtab</name>
            <url>customer/newtab/</url>
            <label>My Special Products</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>


<customer_account translate="label">
 <label>Customer My Special Products</label>
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
     <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="customer/newtab_newtab" name="customer_newtab_newtab" template="customer/newtab/newtab.phtml"/> 
    </reference>
</customer_account>
</layout>
```

My template page is at template\customer\newtab\newtab.phtml

My config.xml for module "Customtabs" is :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
    <Fishpig_Customtabs>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Fishpig_Customtabs>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <customtabs>
            <class>Fishpig_Customtabs_Block</class>
        </customtabs>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <customtabs>
            <class>Fishpig_Customtabs_Model</class>
        </customtabs>
    </models>
     <helpers>
        <customtabs>
            <class>Fishpig_Customtabs_Helper</class>
        </customtabs>
    </helpers>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customtabs>
                <file>Customtabs.xml</file>
            </customtabs>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customtabs>
                <file>customtabs.xml</file>
            </customtabs>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <fishpig_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>customtabs/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                </fishpig_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Any one can help me where is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set url for this tab as `<url>customer/newtab/</url>`
so, you should have controller of `newtab` somewhere,

1. First you need to add `<routers>` part in your module's config.xml, put this in `<frontend>`.

   ```
    <routers>
       <customtabs>
           <use>standard</use>
           <args>
               <module>Fishpig_Customtabs</module>
               <frontName>customtabs</frontName>
           </args>
       </customtabs>
   </routers>
   ```
2. change `<url>customer/newtab/</url>` to `<url>customtabs/newtab</url>` in customtabs.xml file.
   also put,

   ```
   <customtabs_newtab_index>
       <update handle="customer_account"/>
        <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
           <block type="customer/newtab_newtab" name="customer_newtab_newtab" template="customer/newtab/newtab.phtml"/> 
       </reference>
   </customtabs_newtab_index>
   ```
3. create a controller at code/local/Fishpig/Customtabs/controllers/NewtabController.php
4. in that your code should be

   ```
   class Fishpig_Customtabs_NewtabController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {
       public function indexAction()
       {         

           if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
           {
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));
               return false;
           }    
           $this->loadLayout();
           $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');

           $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('My Special Products'));
           $this->renderLayout();
       }

   }
   ```
5. Add a block file as app/code/local/Fishpig/Customtabs/Block/Customtabs.php

and put there code,

```
class Fishpig_Customtabs_Block_Customtabs extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCustomtabs()     
    { 
        if (!$this->hasData('customtabs')) {
            $this->setData('customtabs', Mage::registry('customtabs'));
        }
        return $this->getData('customtabs');

    }
}
```

and change your block type in your customtabs.xml file

```
<block type="customtabs/customtabs" name="customer_newtab_newtab" template="customer/newtab/newtab.phtml" />
```

Comment: Thanks Tejas, 404 error is solved, but page is blank, Means the content of newtab,phtml is not displayed. can you once help on it.

Comment: you set block as "customer/newtab_newtab", you have block file there ?

Comment: Yes i have put newtab.phtm file inside customer/newtab/newtab.phtml

Comment: check point 5 in above answer for how you should create a block file

Comment: I got solution:  <block type="core/template" name="newtab" template="customer/newtab/newtab.phtml"/>

Comment: ya, you can use "core/template", but if you want to add any new function which will be used in newtab.phtml, you need to create separate block file as its not good to put that in "core/template" :)

Comment: thanks for help, i have upload this module on server but when i visit the page "My Special Products" it's give 404 eoor while it's working fine on local. Are you suggests that what is left or wrong...

Comment: ok, now fine, it was my mistake the "controllers" folder name (Controllers) was wrong, all latter should be in lowercase